# how to copy an option value in form list to an input field with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, select

I'm new to javascript and need some help in this matter:

I've created a select field on a form that has some options that have a numeric value.
I need to copy this value to another field in order to add up all several options.
I've already found some code that copy a text input to another field and and a selection to another input field but not the option value.

This is the code i've written so far:

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function id( el ){
        return document.getElementById( el );
}
function getMoney( el ){
        var money = id( el ).value.replace( ',', '.' );
        return parseFloat( money )*100;
}

function soma_oferta()
{
        var total = getMoney('campo16')+getMoney('campo17')+getMoney('campo18')+getMoney('campo19')+getMoney('campo20')+getMoney('campo21');
        id('campo22').value = total/100;
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <form action="" method="">

        <table width="304" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <th colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#999999" scope="col"><h3>Box</h3></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="145" bgcolor="#999999" scope="col"><label for="textfield8"></label>
              Box 1:
                <label for="select9"></label></td>
            <td width="159" bgcolor="#999999" scope="col"><select name="select9" id="select9">
              <option value="5">Option 1</option>
              <option value="10">option 2</option>
              <option value="15">option 3</option>
              </select></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <table width="520" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#999999" scope="col"><h3>&nbsp;</h3></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="98" align="center" bgcolor="#999999" scope="col">Base:</td>
          <td width="165" bgcolor="#999999" scope="col"><input name="campo16" id="campo16" value="0,00" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" scope="col">Box 1:</td>
          <td bgcolor="#999999" scope="col"><input name="campo16" id="campo17" value="0,00" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" scope="col">Box 2:</td>
          <td bgcolor="#999999" scope="col"><input name="campo16" id="campo18" value="0,00" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" scope="col">Box 3:</td>
          <td bgcolor="#999999" scope="col"><input name="campo16" id="campo19" value="0,00" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" scope="col">Extra 1</td>
          <td bgcolor="#999999" scope="col"><input name="campo16" id="campo20" value="0,00" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" scope="col">Extra2:</td>
          <td bgcolor="#999999" scope="col"><input name="campo16" id="campo21" value="0,00" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#999999" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#999999">&nbsp;</td>
          <td bgcolor="#999999">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999">Total:</td>
          <td bgcolor="#999999"><input name="campo16" readonly id="campo22" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#999999"><input type="button" onclick="soma_oferta()" value="Calculate" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p><br />
        <br /><br /><br />
          <br /><br />
      </p>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _"and selection to another input field but not the option value."_ when you get the value of a select box you are getting the currently selected option's value, are you wanting to get one of the non-selected option's value?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected value of the `<select>` with:

```
id('select9').value
```